# Resstarting MongoDB after crash

Tags: mongodb

After a crash of MongoDB I currently cannot restart the database. I cleaned up the .lock file but still get the error:

```
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4880 port=27
017 dbpath=c:/Program Files/MongoDB 2.6 Standard/bin/asd 64-bit host=Lenovo-PC
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Serv
er 2008 R2
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.6
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] git version: 608e8bc319627693b04cc7
da29ecc300a5f45a1f
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsv
ersion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1')
BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2014-12-23T19:55:41.922+0100 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "c:/P
rogram Files/MongoDB 2.6 Standard/bin/asd" } }
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13627 U
nable to create/open lock file: c:/Program Files/MongoDB 2.6 Standard/bin/asd\mo
ngod.lock Zugriff verweigert. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening
sockets...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocat
or...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-12-23T19:55:41.938+0100 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

when exciting mongodb with "mongod --dbpath PATH" where path is the path to the folder, where the database date shoulb be positioned.

The system runs under a virtual environment within windows.

Comment: Have you tried repair? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

Comment: Yes I have tried the flag "--repair" which results in the same error, as still mongodb is excited.

Comment: Maybe a permissions problem on `c:/Program Files/MongoDB 2.6 Standard/bin/asd`? Also you might want to turn on the journalling option for Mongo if you have frequent crashes.